# How to avoid overlapping polygon

Tags: java, drawing, overlap

I created a program to draw many polygons automatically everytimes user presses a button. The points of the polygon are generated automatically using the random function. The problem is that, since the points of the polygon were randomly generated, some of the polygon are overlap with other polygon. How can I avoid this, so that every polygon shown without being overlapped?

```
.....
List<Polygon> triangles = new LinkedList<Polygon>(); 
Random generator = new Random();

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      double xWidth = generator.nextDouble() * 40.0 + 10.0;
      double yHeight = generator.nextDouble() * 40.0 + 10.0;

      xCoord[0] = generator.nextInt(MAX_WIDTH);
      yCoord[0] = generator.nextInt(MAX_HEIGHT); 

      xCoord[1] = (int) (xCoord[0] - xWidth);
      xCoord[2] = (int) (xCoord[1] + (xWidth/2));       

      yCoord[1] = yCoord[0];
      yCoord[2] = (int) (yCoord[1] - yHeight);     

      triangles.add( new Polygon(xCoord,yCoord, 3));          
   }

   Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
   g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
   g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1)); 
   g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 1.00f));
   g2.setPaint(Color.black);//set the polygon line 

   for (Polygon triangle : triangles)  g2.drawPolygon(triangle);

   Polygon[] triArray = triangles.toArray(new Polygon[triangles.size()]);
   for (Polygon p:triArray) triangles.remove (p);

}
```

Comment: So to reiterate (so I don't have to read the code at length), you're generating 10-sided polygons in series, and you don't want them to overlap?

Comment: yes.The size of my JPanel is 600*600, I want the polygons to be displayed without being overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the game programming wiki on Polygon Collision:

http://gpwiki.org/index.php/Polygon_Collision

Answer (score 1):

You could break your canvas into 10 regions and constrain your polygons each to their own region.  To do this, you could use your `i` value and a `%100` (or other suitable magnitude) of your randomly generated value and apply them to your x coordinates and y coordinates as applicable.  The result would be a grid of similarly constrained(no larger than the grid cell), but randomly shaped, Polygons.

EDIT:

Taking another look and fooling around a bit, I took the general concept as I described above and made a stab at an implementation:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    int[] xCoord = new int[3];
    int[] yCoord = new int[3];
    int colCnt = 5;
    int rowCnt = 2;
    int maxCellWidth = getWidth() / colCnt;
    int maxCellHeight = getHeight() / rowCnt;

    for (int i = 0; i < (colCnt * rowCnt); i++) {
        int xMultiple = i % colCnt;
        int yMultiple = i / colCnt;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
         xCoord[j] = generator.nextInt(maxCellWidth)
                   + (maxCellWidth * xMultiple);
             yCoord[j] = generator.nextInt(maxCellHeight)
                   + (maxCellHeight * yMultiple);
        }
        triangles.add(new Polygon(xCoord, yCoord, 3));
    }
    //... the rest of your method
}
```

As you can see, all of the Polygons have all points randomly generated, as opposed to your method of generating the first point and then making the rest relative to the first.     There is a sense of randomness that is lost, however, as the Polygons are laid out in a grid-like pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Create Area objects from your new polygon as well as for all existing polygons.
Subtract the new polygon's area from the existing ones. If the subtract changed the area, the polygons overlap.

```
Area newArea = new Area(newPolygon);
Area existingArea = new Area(existingPolygon);
Area existingAreaSub = new Area(existingPolygon); existingAreaSub.subtract(newArea);
boolean intersects = existingAreaSub.equals(existingArea);
```

Comment: Try to insert the code but it keep giving me error: Type mismatch cannot convert from void to Area. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a method `Polycon.containsPoint( x, y )` and repeat your random generation until this method returns `false` for all drawn Polygons.

Answer (score -1):

I have achieved this in Android Using Kotlin ([See github project](https://github.com/MaheshKumarPrajapati/MapboxWithGraphNavigation)) by using JTS [see here](http://www.tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html#intersects(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry))

**Step-1:**
Add JTS library to your project

```
implementation group: 'org.locationtech.jts', name: 'jts-core', version: '1.15.0'
```

**Step-2:**

Create JTS polygon objects for both polygon

```
// create polygons One
        var polygoneOneArray: ArrayList<Coordinate> = ArrayList()
        for (points in polygonOnePointsList) {
            polygoneOneArray.add(Coordinate(points.latitude(), points.longitude()))
        }
        val polygonOne: org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon = GeometryFactory().createPolygon(
                polygoneOneArray.toTypedArray()
        )

// create polygons Two
        var polygoneTwoArray: ArrayList<Coordinate> = ArrayList()
        for (points in polygoneTwoPointsList) {
            polygoneTwoArray.add(Coordinate(points.latitude(), points.longitude()))
        }
        val polygonTwo: org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon = GeometryFactory().createPolygon(
                polygoneTwo.toTypedArray()
        )
```

**Step-3:**

Get Common Area of both Polygon

```
val intersection: org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry = polygonOne.intersection(polygonTwo)
```

**Step-4:**

Remove common Area from polygonTwo

```
 val difference: org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry = polygonTwo.difference(intersection)
```

**Step-5:**

Merge Both polygonOne and update polygonTwo

```
val union: org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry = mergePolygonList.get(0).polygons.union(difference)
```

**Step-5:**

Now pick points from Geometry and draw a final merged Polygon

```
   val array: ArrayList<Coordinate> = union.coordinates.toList() as ArrayList<Coordinate>
    val pointList: ArrayList<Point> = ArrayList()
    for (item in array) {
        pointList.add(Point.fromLngLat(item.y, item.x))
    }
    var list: ArrayList<List<Point>> = ArrayList<List<Point>>()
    list.add(pointList)
    style.addSource(
            GeoJsonSource(
                    "source-id${timeStamp}",
                    Feature.fromGeometry(Polygon.fromLngLats(list))
            )
    )
```