# Arranging triangles in grid order

Tags: java, geometry

My program generated triangles automatically, however the arrangement of the triangles are random on JPanel. How can I plot the triangle in a grid order? Thanks.

EDITED:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)    
{ 

  xCoord[0] = generator.nextInt(MAX_WIDTH);
  yCoord[0] = generator.nextInt(MAX_HEIGHT);

  xCoord[1] = (int) (xCoord[0] - xWidth);
  xCoord[2] = (int) (xCoord[1] + (xWidth/2));         

  yCoord[1] = yCoord[0];
  yCoord[2] = (int) (yCoord[1] - yHeight);  

  triangles.add( new Polygon(xCoord,yCoord, 3)); 
}
```

EDITED: OUTPUT DESIRED

How can I make the program generate many pattern but it **MUST** be in **symmetrical** form? e.g. **left and right** is symmetrical. I've tried to make Loop but so far it only generate 1 pattern. Help please :-(

```
*** ***      OR    **   **        OR  ***   ***    etc (as long as it is symmetrical)
*** ***            **   **             *     *
 *   *
```

Comment: When submitting homework problems, it's best to show your work so that people can give guidance.

Comment: Do you want to plot triangles one at a time? Or triangle parts? Can a triangle include part of another triangle? Do they have a specific orientation?

Comment: The size of the triangles are similar. There are 10 triangles I would like to arrange it orderly on JPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [my solution to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546143/how-to-avoid-overlapping-polygon/1546301#1546301).

EDIT:

Modifying the example in the link above, you can replace the randomized Polygon points with some that are more fixed.  In the `paintComponent` method, you can replace:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    xCoord[j] = generator.nextInt(maxCellWidth)
                    + (maxCellWidth * xMultiple);
    yCoord[j] = generator.nextInt(maxCellHeight)
                    + (maxCellHeight * yMultiple);
}
```

with this:

```
xCoord[0] = (maxCellWidth/2) + (maxCellWidth * xMultiple);
// use the following if you need the points to be fixed as well.
//xCoord[0] = generator.nextInt(maxCellWidth) + (maxCellWidth * xMultiple);
yCoord[0] = 5 + (maxCellHeight * yMultiple);
xCoord[1] = 5 + (maxCellWidth * xMultiple);
yCoord[1] = maxCellHeight - 5 + (maxCellHeight * yMultiple);
xCoord[2] = maxCellWidth - 5 + (maxCellWidth * xMultiple);
yCoord[2] = maxCellHeight - 5 + (maxCellHeight * yMultiple);
```

For fun, uncommenting the second setting of xCoord[0] will make the top point in a random spot along to x-axis, but the bottom two points of the triangles will be fixed and have a constant distance between them.

[alt text http://img127.imageshack.us/img127/5809/picture5v.png](http://img127.imageshack.us/img127/5809/picture5v.png)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make it equal space from one triangles to another?

Comment: e.g there are 10 triangles, how can I make it so the distance of one triangles from one another are fixed e.g. 20

Comment: do you still want them to be randomly shaped?

Comment: No. the triangle size are fixed. There are only one size of all.

Comment: I need the arrangement of the triangles look symmetrical (gird order might be the best order), both from left and right side of the JPanel.

Comment: that should be easy then.  you can still take my code(link above) with its iteration and remove the randomizing aspect.  just start with the triangle size you want and iterate, calculating the point offsets based on your cell.

Answer (score 0):

If your triangles are not all the same size, shape and orientation (or only approximately), then you could place them such that their circumcentre points are on a precise grid, giving you an approximation of being "equally" spaced. You can try other points, such as the centre of the nine-point circle to see if you can find a visually more pleasing arrangement.

See the [Wikipedia article on triangles][1] for more information about these points.

[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle"Wikipedia article on triangles"